# nginx logging wrong login password

Tags: nginx

I would like to see on nginx logs when someone tries to log into my server and put a wrong password. On /var/log/nginx/error.log I don't see the errors

```
2016/08/12 08:45:14 [error] 1282#0: *25820 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications?format=json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:45:55 [error] 1282#0: *25727 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while sending request to upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "POST /index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:46:04 [error] 1280#0: *25849 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications?format=json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:46:14 [error] 1282#0: *25820 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications?format=json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:46:56 [error] 1282#0: *25727 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while sending request to upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "POST /index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:47:04 [error] 1280#0: *25859 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications?format=json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:47:15 [error] 1282#0: *25820 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v1/notifications?format=json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
2016/08/12 08:52:03 [error] 1282#0: *25727 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.147.166.217, server: 172.31.0.10, request: "POST /index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysecurecloud.ddns.net"
```

Also, I have tried to change the log level following some guides on internet but the commands are not recognized

```
2016/08/12 11:47:44 [emerg] 32543#0: unknown log format "info" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
2016/08/12 11:48:54 [emerg] 32556#0: unknown log format "warn" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
```

Any idea?